# how to get meta tags with php, but with html form

Tags: php, html

I got this PHP `src`:

```
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.autostraddle.com');
echo "CMS is: ";
echo $tags['generator'];
```

This code is not user friendly; it's not ready for one online tool for my website, because I want create a simple service - CMS detector, and...

```
$tag = isset($_REQUEST['url']) ? get_meta_tags('url') : '';


<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="url" size="65" value="<?php echo $tag;  ?>"/><br />
<input type="submit" value="Go!">

echo $tag['generator'];
```

I want create one online tool about detecting what CMS is, but I need this PHP script with HTML form because this will be used from users, and not only from me.

They must put any url, and then the script will perform as described to get the meta tag 'generator'; how do I get the meta tag 'generator'? I want only this meta tag.

Well, and how to do this with 'if else'? if there is meta tag generator do this, but if there is not such tag 'generator', then write any 'echo' message, e.g.

> CMS is not known.

Well, this is simple PHP script, but I don't know how to create variables and how to get a URL; mayve with cURL?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: *Ah,* the Welcome Wagon! ^ - @JayBlanchard Thoughtful of you *Sam!*

Comment: Trying to share a little kindness before the DV wolves arrive @Fred-ii-. *Besides Sam, the stuff I've been mired in all day makes me look forward to playing a little music around the proverbial campfire tonight and I'm trying to calm the frustration first ;-)*

Comment: Ahh yes; I can't wait for those *round the fire pick-alongs ♫ Sam!* @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're struggling with is actually getting the user-side input from the POST superglobals. This is something you can try, but there are many ways to implement this. You could also use `method="SET"` and capture the user parameters from URL of the `action=""` file.

Notice, in this case, the `action=""` parameter is empty. That means the PHP script will execute on the same page where the HTML form is. This might not be what you're trying to do, so if you need to redirect, add the PHP code to a separate file and add it to your website and to the `action=""` parameter.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="url" size="65" placeholder="http://yoururl"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $tags = get_meta_tags($_POST['url']);
    if($tags['generator'])
         echo "CMS: <b>" . $tags['generator'] . "</b><br>";
    else
         echo "No CMS info available.<br>";
}
?>
```

Give this a shot.

Comment: wow:) so fast:) great! haha super! thank you very much! work great! but i will put 'http://' in da html form, because without http:// not work... it can't get... but with http:// in a field work fine... thank you thank you thank you:)))))))) [_]> beer for you haha:) well, god bless you!!!

Comment: @MilenStoichev Great, nice to see you're learning. Please accept the answer by clicking the tick-mark on the top left.